# Executing 'start' in runtime process

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I am trying to start a steam application via java code.

First, I had to figure out a way to open it using cmd, which was pretty easy, I just had to type in `start steam://rungameid/xxx`

And now, I need my java program to open the application

This is what I have tried so far.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start steam://rungameid/xxx");
```

and

`new ProcessBuilder("start", "steam://rungameid/xxx").start()`

Both of them resulted an IOException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue, so I just need a helping hand.

Comment: @arundeepchohan 'start' is a built in command, It's not a file.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start steam://rungameid/xxx"");

Comment: Try that instead.

Comment: It's working, Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start steam://rungameid/xxx"");
```

Problem was not finding how to run the start.